# Referencing variables in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

Simple version:
I have a list of arrays that reference page elements, like so:

```
var listOfArrays = ["header", "middle", "footer"];
```

and arrays like so for each:

```
var header = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var middle = ["carrot", "cucumber", "asparagus"];
var footer = ["earth", "air", "water"];
```

I'd like to be able to replace the HTML of the page elements dynamically by running through an array, like so:

```
for(i=0; i<listOfArrays.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(listOfArrays[i]).innerHTML({listOfArrays[i]}[cycleNumber]);
}
```

The output I'd like would be the three elements changed to read "red", "carrot", and "earth", respectively (at least for the first cycle, which is all I'm concerned about).
How should I code this?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pv73qnxo/1/) is a jsfiddle with a model of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create an additionally array containing the other arrays:

```
var IDs = ["header", "middle", "footer"];

var parts = [
    ["red", "blue", "green"],
    ["carrot", "cucumber", "asparagus"],
    ["earth", "air", "water"]
];

for (var i=0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(IDs[i]).innerHTML = parts[i][cycleNumber];
}
```

Now, the disadvantage is that it is not very maintainable. If you add a new element to `IDs`, you have to rearrange `parts` accordingly.

A slightly better solution is to use an object as a lookup map:

```
var IDs = ["header", "middle", "footer"];

var parts = {
    header: ["red", "blue", "green"],
    middle: ["carrot", "cucumber", "asparagus"],
    footer: ["earth", "air", "water"]
};

for (var i=0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
    var ID = IDs[i];
    document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = parts[ID][cycleNumber];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, though it might be (I expect it is) that my Javascript function is broken.
https://jsfiddle.net/zzrmvwa7/

Comment: I guess you haven't seen my update yet. And if you look at the console you will see that your code is invalid: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.

Comment: The edit doesn't work for me either.
https://jsfiddle.net/zzrmvwa7/1/
I'll investigate the error, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, additionally, `innerHTML` is a string, not a function. You cannot call it, you have to assign to it. What made you think it is a function?

Comment: Inexperience. What would you recommend I use instead?

Comment: As I said, you have to *assign* to it. `element.innerHTML = 'some new HTML';`. Oh, and I just noticed that you are using `listOfArrays` also as IDs.... let me update my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Here's the final, working jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/zzrmvwa7/2/

The assign/function mixup was embarrassing: thank you for catching that. It was correctly written in my original code but I didn't proofread my retype here.